# renaming files using regular expression with linux

Tags: regex, linux, file, rename

I have read quite a few questions here and on the interwebz, however my file renaming still doesn't work. I've got a bunch of files that starts as follows:

```
libraryVCE_KM_LIBRARY_SUMARY_S...
```

I want to remove the first instance of library, so I run this command in linux:

```
rename -v '/\blibrary/' *
```

However no files are renamed. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
rename library '' *
```

And it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rename 's/^library//' *
```

Comment: @Sniffer. That's Perl substitution operator. `s///`.